topology of unrdered product of $\mathbb{RP}^2$
Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ be the quotient space $X\times X/\sim$ where the equivalence relation is defined as follows: $(x_1,x_2)\sim (x_2,x_1)$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $(x,x)\sim(y,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. In other words, this is taking unordered pair of points in $X$ and moding out the diagonal. I wonder if there is a relation between the homology of $Y$ and the homology of $X$. When $X=S^1$, we know that $Y=\mathbb{RP}^2$. I am particularly interested in the homology of $Y$ when $X=\mathbb{RP}^2$.
